Show that the formula above completely defines the mapping $g : \mathbb R^{n*} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ (Arnol'd)
This question is mildly paraphrased from Arnol'd's Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics page 64. I have included the information that I thought was germane, but if you feel something is missing then feel free to go check out the page. I used a different approach than what Arnol'd seems to be suggesting, but I can't really figure out what he wanted.

Have the inner product $\cdot$ between two vectors. Have vectors $\alpha, x \in \mathbb R^n$. Let $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a convex function, with the Legendre transform
$$g \alpha = \sup(\alpha \cdot x - fx)$$
Show that the formula above completely defines the mapping $g : \mathbb R^{n*} \rightarrow \mathbb R$ (under the condition that the linear form $df|_x$ ranges over all of $\mathbb R^{n*}$ when $x$ ranges over $\mathbb R^n$.

Proof:
Our vectors form a complete real Hilbert space. Then the Riesz representation theorem (RRT) holds, which means that for an appropriate choice of inner product $\cdot
$  and dualspace isomorphism  $\text ? ^\intercal $ , we have an equivalent $$ v \cdot u = v^\intercal u $$
By the RRT we can rewrite the Legendre transformation as $$g\alpha^\intercal = \sup(\alpha ^\intercal x - fx)$$
if we mildly redefine $g$ to operate on forms instead of vectors.
QED

Is this strategy of using RRT to get my answer acceptable? It seems like Arnol'd wanted me to take the exterior derivative of $f$ and use it to get my answer, but RRT seems like it can give a fast and clean proof. Let me know if you have a better way of proving this (perhaps using Arnol'ds hint in the question), or if my RRT proof is incorrect. Cheers!

I do not think that this is what Arnold wants you to do. He defines $g$ as $$g(\mathbf{p})=\max_\mathbf{x}{(\mathbf p,x)\color{red}-f(\mathbf x)}$$ where I am fixing a sign error of yours. The term $(\mathbf p,x)$ is the ordinary inner product in $\mathbb R^n,.$ In order that $g$ is defined on all of $\mathbb R^{n*}$ we have to use the convexity of $f$ plus the surjectivity of $\mathbf x\mapsto df|_{\mathbf x}$ to show that for every $\mathbf p$ the maximum is attained for some $\mathbf x,.$

@KurtG. Typo is fixed. You're saying that this is an existence of solution type problem? After proving that there's a maximizing $x$, for Arnol'd's definition, does applying the RRT to get the new $g$ function work?

When we accept that $(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{x})$ is the ordinary inner product in $\mathbb R^n$ I do not see any reason whatsoever to call in an RRT strike. I could not quite follow your post in this regard. Our linear functional and our Hilbert space are lying in front of us as plain as day.

@KurtG. The question says we need to define the Legendre transformation $g$ on the dual space, but in Arnol'd's example it's defined on the vector space.

Think of it. An author who is best known fot his anti-Bourbakism wants you to use  Hilbert space methods to show  in a physics book that the dual space of $\mathbb R^n$ (column vectors) is the space of row vectors of lenght $n,.$ Absurd.

@Kurt G. Haha, if you want to get feisty on me then I'll say that I think isomorphic dual spaces suck and that an equivalent inner product is cleaner and conceptually easier to handle (like with Riemannian metrics) =p. But Arnol'd very specifically wrote that to prove his Legendre transform is acting on the dual space, and I'm not going to question his problem statement. If you want to, you can write the proof that you want and I'll happily give you the answer point.

For the life of me I do not see what sucks in finite dimensions. On the contrary, I agree that functional analysis sucks. ;)

You did not prove much, you just trivially redefined $g$ to $\tilde g$ on the original space rather than the natural dual space. It is not very insightful as the RRT depends on the choice of the dot product, so your new $\tilde g$ depends on $f$ and the arbitrary dot product, while the usual Legendre transform $g$ depends only on $f$. You still have not addressed the original question whether $g$ is well defined in the first place.
There is no need for exterior differentiation, only take the differential. The goal of the problem is prove that the $\sup$ is finite. For this, you will need the crucial assumption that $f$ is convex and $df$ ranges over the entire dual space (which you did not use). Intuitively, this is would be desirable, because assuming that the $\sup$ is obtained at a finite value $x$, by variation:
$$
df_x = \alpha
$$
and since $\alpha$ ranges over the entire dual space, you would need $df_x$ to range over it as well.
For the actual proof, start by convexity. The differential plane is under the epigraph, so for all vectors $x$ and $y$:
$$
f(y)\geq f(x)+\langle df_x,y-x\rangle
$$
Therefore, let $\alpha$ be in the range of $df$ and $x$ such that $\alpha = df_x$, then for all $y$:
$$
\langle \alpha,y\rangle-f(y) \leq \langle \alpha,x\rangle-f(x) <\infty
$$
Therefore, the upper bound is finite. Thus $g$ is well defined in the range of $df$, and since it is the entire dual space, it is defined on the entire dual space. Actually, this proves a slightly stronger result, the Legendre transform of a convex function is defined on the range of its differential.
